# How to change brightness color which drawing image from the pdf?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented pdf reader application.In which i have drawn image from the pdf.But problem is that generated image is very dark how to solve this issue.

Please help me for this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated this issue about a month ago.

I suggest you to read [this forum thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10094-adjust-image-brightness-contrast-fly.html).